# Can I remove some packages with one command?

Tags: package-management, uninstall

I want to remove all `apache` packages from my system (as I am transitioning to `lighttpd`).

I have these installed :

```
monkey@debVirtual:/etc/php5dpkg --get-selections | grep apachee]
apache2-doc                                     install
apache2-mpm-itk                                 install
apache2-utils                                   install
apache2.2-bin                                   deinstall
apache2.2-common                                install
libapache2-mod-dnssd                            install
libapache2-mod-perl2                            deinstall
libapache2-mod-php5                             install
libapache2-mod-python                           install
```

`

```
monkey@debVirtual:/etc/php5$ whereis apache2
apache2: /usr/sbin/apache2 /etc/apache2 /usr/lib/apache2 /usr/lib64/apache2 /usr/share/apache2 /usr/share/man/man8/apache2.8.gz
```

I would like to use one dpkg (or other) command to remove (totally from my system) all apache packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command to remove a package and its configuration is `apt-get purge`. It can accept multiple package names as argument:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2-mpm-itk apache2-utils apache2.2-bin and so on
```

It may happen that `/etc/apache2` remains untouched after removal, in that case remove it manually with:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2
```

Be careful when typing this command or you may regret it.